# How to POST data from a field with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-post

Hi I am trying to make a page which will use the `$.post` method in Javascript to post the data from a live text field through to another script when the space bar is pressed. I want the data from a the page known as *index.php* to be posted through another file called *save.php*. I want to the value of `txt_a` textfield to to be the value of the post varible `text`. How would I do this? Below is my code so far...

```
<html>   
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function event_a() {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
               $(document).ready(function(){
                   txt=$document.getElementsByName('txt_a')[0].value;
                   $.post("save.php",{text:txt});
               };
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="" action="">
        <input name="txt_a" type="text" id="txt_a" onkeypress="event_a()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
$(function(){

    $('#txt_a').keyup(function(e){

        if(e.which === 13) {

            $.post('save.php',{text: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                //do something with the response
            });
        }

    });

});
```

And in **save.php**:

```
$text = isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : null;
```

Comment: @DanielLarkin Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript function should look more like this:

```
function event_a(event) { // event needs to be defined as arg to use.
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { // ready is used to trigger code when the page is ready, not needed here
    var txt=$('txt_a').val(); // assuming you are using jQuery, you can access the value like this
    $.post("save.php",{text:txt});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing variable from one file to the another? Use  $_SESSION to save and retrieve the set data/variable in multiple pages .